# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to initialize ehcache via XML file

Tags: java, weblogic, classloader, ehcache, saxon

I have randomly this problem when I try to initialize ehcache:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct private cerebro84.util.cache.CacheManagerServiceBean.initialize() on cerebro84.util.cache.CacheManagerServiceBean@3ee90439
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:405)
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:178)
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:298)
                at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
                at cerebro84.util.cache.CacheManagerServiceBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getFromCache(CacheManagerServiceBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
                at cerebro84.util.cache.CacheMethodInterceptor.getResultFromCache(CacheMethodInterceptor.java:29)
                ... 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
                at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
                at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
                at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
                at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:168)
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:403)
                ... 210 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/trans/XPathException
                at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformerHandler.startDocument(IdentityTransformerHandler.java:110)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader$State.<init>(DomLoader.java:83)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.startElement(DomLoader.java:118)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ProxyLoader.startElement(ProxyLoader.java:60)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:528)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:507)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:75)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:178)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:348)
                at org.ehcache.xml.ConfigurationParser.<init>(ConfigurationParser.java:177)
                at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.parseConfiguration(XmlConfiguration.java:178)
                at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:166)
                at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:134)
                at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider$ConfigSupplier.getConfiguration(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:327)
                at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:127)
                at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:78)
                at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:186)
                at cerebro84.util.cache.CacheManagerServiceBean.initialize(CacheManagerServiceBean.java:38)
                ... 220 more
```

The weird behavior is that if I restarted the container (weblogic), it works fine. This is the class I use to initialize the cache, trimming down to the bare essential:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.Caching;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@ApplicationScoped
public class CacheManagerServiceBean {
    private static final String EHCACHE_CONFIG_FILE_PATH = "/ehcache.xml";
    @Getter
    private CacheManager cacheManager = null;
    @Getter
    private boolean cacheEnabled = false;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        logger.info("Instantiating cache manager");
        try {
            this.cacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager(
                    getClass().getResource(EHCACHE_CONFIG_FILE_PATH).toURI(),
                    getClass().getClassLoader());
            cacheEnabled = true;
        } catch (Exception|NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            logger.error("Unable to enable cache", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add the following line

```
<wls:package-name>net.sf.saxon.*</wls:package-name>
```

to `/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml`, but this did't help. Saxon is a direct dependancy of the module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.5.1-8</version>
</dependency>
```

The module is packaged as `jar` in a `ear` multimodule application. 
Does anybody have any idea on how to make sure that the class `XPathException` is always found by saxon? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are usually caused by having several different versions of Saxon on the classpath at the same time.

Comment: right I think so too; in this case we can see ehcache scanning the classpath looking for configuration (org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.parseConfiguration), and apparently it found a dead end when it stubbled upon Saxon

Comment: Thank you, I found that saxon9he is indeed duplicate thanks to tattletale, but they are both on the same version, both containing  `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException`. Is this an issue anyway? I don't have a way to always reproduce the bug, so I will not be sure to have fixed it by removing the duplication until I have issues again..

Comment: I think it can be a problem even if they are the same version, if they were loaded from different JAR files by different classloaders. But classloading issues always seem to involve an element of black magic, and a lot depends on the application framework you are using, so it's hard to offer specific help.